# AS3 SWC component create library instance

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, custom-component

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me with the following question.

I would like to know if it is possible for an AS3 component on the flash authoring stage to instantiate images from the current document (fla)'s library and display them in the component on the stage during Live Preview.

To clarify this imagine if you were to create a new fla, place the Adobe UILoader component on the stage and when you set the source (which in this case would be an image from the fla library) it would show the image in the UILoader. This does not happen with the UILoader of course but that is what I am trying to achieve.

I know that one can do URL loading of images from an external source during Live Preview but what I am looking for is loading of the current document's library resources.

Any assistance would be greatly and deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UILoader.loadbytes(yourBitmapDataAsByteArray);

You should be able to get it to load the image using the loadBytes() function. 
First make you image  a bytearray.

```
   var libraryImage:Bitmap = new LibraryImage(Width, Height);
   var myBitmapData:BitmapData = libraryImage.bitmapData; 
   var bytes:ByteArray = myBitmapData.getPixels(myBitmapdData.rect);
   myUILoader.loadBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: thanks I did try that which would work when you compile the fla. What needs to happen is that the image should display in the UILoader during authoring when setting the source of the component.

The UILoader would have no knowledge that there is a class called LibraryImage and therefore I made an adjustment to the code above to reflect that:

var c:Class = getDefinitionByName("LibraryImage") as Class;
var bmp:BitmapData = new c(0,0) as BitmapData;

Comment: However the above code would only work when you compile the document and it loads in the image. What needs to happen is that the UILoader component (Which I have subclassed into a new UILoader component) needs to display the image during authoring on the stage.